# Flutter : Flutter Emulator cant open Camera (flutter_emulator:5554)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

[image]
I'm trying test my App with Emulator Device. I'm already use 3 different Emulator (Nexus,Google Pixel 2 and Flutter_emulator:5554).

If open camera at Nexus and Google Pixel,it's working fine. But every try open camera in Flutter_emulator , camera crash with pop up 
`Camera Keeps Stopping`

> In console message, not show me any error.

Comment: I think the emulator does not support to access camera

Comment: Hmmmm,make sense.

Comment: Something such as camera, micro, you should check on real device.